# Mplayer in fullscreen in xmonad

Tags: mplayer, xmonad

Is it possible to run `mplayer` in fullscreen in `xmonad`?

When I use the `-fullscreen` switch or `f` command it does nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put `fstype=none` in your `~/.mplayer/config`.

For more discussion about this see [this issue in the xmonad issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/xmonad/issues/detail?id=333).

Comment: This helped but without `=` sign. The switch should be only `fstype none`.